# How to check if array of object contains a string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

let's say I have an array of objects:

```
let arr = [
   {
    name: 'Jack',
    id: 1
   },
   {
    name: 'Gabriel',
    id: 2
   },
   {
    name: 'John',
    id: 3
   }
]
```

I need to check whether that array includes the name 'Jack' for example using:

```
if (arr.includes('Jack')) {
   // don't add name to arr

} else {
  // push name into the arr

}
```

but arr.includes('Jack') returns false, how can I check if an array of objects includes the name?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you need to check the object property value in the array, you can try with [`Array​.prototype​.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```js
let arr = [
   {
    name: 'Jack',
    id: 1
   },
   {
    name: 'Gabriel',
    id: 2
   },
   {
    name: 'John',
    id: 3
   }
]
var r = arr.some(i => i.name.includes('Jack'));
console.log(r);
```

Comment: For single value it is working. What if I need to check for array of values like ["John", "Jack"]]?

Comment: @UI_Brain, simply omit the property *name* - `arr.some(i => i.includes('Jack'));`